# How to create the folder using php code under the user perm in developement server?

Tags: linux, php, php5

We have Development Server with apache 2.2 and php5. Here developers are accessing the server using the individual samba login for uploading the files into the server. But when creating the folder and files using the php code, it  creating under the apache user and group perm. So, may i know how to create the folder and file using php code under individual login. Is there any changes need to done in php.ini or apache configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

- http://suphp.org/ to use PHP as your user (which might be dangerous)
- set the gid on that folder (`g+s`) so all the files created there will belong to your user's group as well (and not apache's)

Comment: This helped me as well, however, when apache creates files, they have group perms set to `r--` and `r-x` for directories. So, the group that the user belongs to does not have perms to delete/modify the file. How can I overcome this?