# Right file owner/group for files created by apache and required to be editable by local user

Tags: apache-2.2

I am running apache on a MacOSX Lion machine. I've got this site (Joomla 1.5) that creates files in the `cache` directory or it's subdirectories. There are instances when the subdirectories are also created by apache.

When files and directories are created by apache, they end up with the `group:user` set to `_www:_www` (apache user on mac).

Problem is, I often want to delete these files while I'm logged in with my credentials (say `code_poet`). I'm not part of the `_www` group, so obviously, I cannot delete these files as these files typically have `rwxr_xr_x` set.

My question, therefore is how best to get around this problem, without adding myself to the `_www` group (I'm not even sure if I could add myself to that group). A workaround obviously is to use `sudo`, but that doesn't work if I'm trying to do a delete via a UI tool like `SmartGit`.

PS: I'm not too familiar with these unix like permission concepts but I read something about mask bit and tried to set the `cache` folder perms to `u+rws` while having the `cache` folder perms `owner:group` set to `code_poet:www`, but it does not achieve the desired result.

If I understood correctly, files/directories created under this folder should inherit the owner id from the parent.

Comment: Found a partial answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/373750/how-to-create-the-folder-using-php-code-under-the-user-perm-in-developement-serv. Now, however, when apache creates a file, while they do have the group set to `staff` (my group on mac), the perms for group are `r--`. So naturally, I cannot edit/delete the file without a `sudo`. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the files owned by your user account, and group owned by apache. Then make them group writable, so that both you and apache can write to them.

```
chown -R user._www /path/to/cache
chmod -R ug+w,o-w /path/to/cache
```

Comment: I have this done already. The problem is when apache creates a directory inside cache, that directory ends up with `group:owner` set to `_www:_www`. Then I cannot delete those directories without a `sudo`.

Comment: When files are created in this folder they have perms for group set to 'r-x', so I'm not able to edit/delete them.